# If something is in a good working order, should I write 'it works' or 'it is working'?

Tags: present-tense

Usually, I know when to use Present Simple or Present Continuous but here I have two examples which I'm not sure about.

I want to sell a laptop and state in the description that it is in working order. Should I use present continuous or present simple? I think that the correct option is 'The laptop works well', not 'The laptop is working well' but I'm not sure about that.

The next question and again a laptop! :) The laptop has a cracked bezel (that's a frame around the screen) and I want to say that 'it is not coming off' or 'it doesn't come off'. Which one is correct? Please help me and describe why if you can :) If something is not clear I will try to describe it better.

Comment: The difference between "it works well" and "it is working well" is that the former is used in a more general context. I, and most other native speakers, would only use "it is working well" when the laptop was actually switched on. If we wanted to say (as you do) that the laptop works well on all occasions when it is used we would say "it works well". Describing the bezel, however, is a bit more complicated. If you wanted to say that the bezel never comes off you would say "it doesn't come off" but if you wanted to say the bezel wasn't getting worse you would say "it's not coming off".

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply! So that's exactly what I thought. I want to say that it works because I'm not pointing exact date in the past and I don't want to say that it is switched on and working right now.
Just to make sure, if I bought the laptop and the bezel was glued, how should I say that? Because I think I should say that 'it's not coming off' (now, after the repair). Am I right?
Best Regards

Comment: If the bezel has been stuck together in such a way that the clips now hold it on you could say that the bezel has been repaired by gluing, if you have had to glue the bezel to the screen or the lid you would have to say that the bezel had been secured using glue. The difference is that repairing the bezel does not stop someone from replacing the screen even if they need to fit an unrepaired bezel but sticking the bezel onto the lid could make that repair impossible.